# Determine where a user has selected a song in the MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller

Once a user has selected a song in the picker, is there a way to determine *where* the user had selected the song, i.e. In the songs or playlist tab, or if the song was selected as a part of a single album or a list containing all albums of a particular artist.

Just wondering if at all this was possible with the `MPMediaPickerController` instead of creating a new navigator from scratch.

Thanks!

Comment: you got any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no, and creating a new navigator is not as difficult as you might imagine.